# Angular UI.Router script includes

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angularjs application which is defined on multiple html pages within a website. On one of the pages is using `ui.router` to change some view states without navigating away from this page. As the `$stateProvider` is injected at the angular app level, it appears I have to reference the `ui.router` script in all of the html page even where it is not actually being used.

i.e the following has to be included on pages where routing is not even being used but other parts of the angular application are.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/1.0.3/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
```

Is there a way to setup `ui.router` on a single application without having to include a reference to the script on every html page? I'm just trying to avoid loading resources on pages unnecessarily.

Comment: sounds like "Accelerated Mobile Pages" (AMP) or "lazy loading" concepts

Comment: not sure, I'm just trying to avoid loading external resources on pages where they are not being used :-)

Comment: Technically, there are ways to do lazy loading of **angular components**.  However, `ui-router` is not a component;  in order to work, it modifies the module configuration, which is done during bootstrapping.  Therefore, `ui-router` must be present for the entire life cycle of the app.

Comment: Also, to be clear, there is a distinction between **pages** that the code is present on and **views** that the code is present on.  Unless you are using multiple angular apps on different **pages**, it seems like you are probably using both angular router and `ui-router`, and it might make more sense to leverage one or the other more and phase the other out.  And if you *are* using multiple angular apps, then you are bootstrapping on each page change; you would not need to include `ui-router` on the that don't use it.  This isn't a very efficient way to use angular, though....

Comment: Thanks, I think the problem I have is although I'm using angular the site is not technically a spa as there are multiple html pages within the site. I'm only using <pre>ui-router</pre> and not angular routing. It's single app with multiple controllers with the controllers doing grunt work on various pages. However the angular app is included on all of the pages where controllers are being used hence the need to include the ui.router reference on all of the pages I guess.

Comment: if you are using a single app.js and loading it across multiple html pages, you are bound to have problems.  You are going to be tempted to treat the app and all the data like it's all in sync, but in reality the app is going to be reloaded from scratch every time you switch pages.  This is likely to cause random, hard to trace bugs that are related to data from one page not really being loaded on the next page;  In general, it leads to code that's harder to understand.

Comment: If using angular on multiple html pages is a necessity, you should force yourself to use a unique JavaScript file for each new page.  This will stop you from thinking that the resources from one page are available on the next, and will also insulate you from the need to have a dependency included on every page because it's used once in your massive app.js.  You only have to include the ui-router script on the page that loads an angular module that uses it.  **However, it would be better for you to find a way to leverage ui-router or angular routing and actually convert your app to a SPA.**